# dropdown menu inside iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have a bit of a problem. I made a blog for my webpage, and I use the header of it in my blog.

The thing is, I have a drop down menu which includes a pretty long menu, so when used in the blog, the iframe does not show all of it, only the first few options.

I'm wondering whether there is a way to make that iframe extends or allow the menu to show the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should include the header server side instead of embedding it using an iframe. How you do this depends on what platform you're using.

If you are using **plain html**, the simplest option is to just copy the header. If you are using IIS you could extract the header to its own file and include it using **SSI**:

```
<!--#include file="header.html"-->
```

If you're using some kind of **templating system**, perhaps you could extract the header so that it exists in its own template file and then include it where needed. Using Django:

```
{% include "header.html" %}
```

If you have a homebrew site, perhaps you are using **PHP**? Then you could just include it like this, of course:

```
<?php include('header.html'); ?>
```